# python-mysql connector table creation code

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

```
import mysql.connector


x=mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='subru',database='netflix')
print(x)
c=x.cursor()
a=1
def create_input():
    b=input('enter table name')
    n=int(input('enter number of columns'))
    s=''
    for i in range(n):
        if i==0:
            s=s+'(%s,'
        elif i==n-1:
            s=s+'%s)'
        else:
            s=s+'%s,'
    print(type(s))
    print(s)
    L=()
    for i in range(n):
        c1=input('enter column name')
        c2=input('enter column specs')
        z='{} {}'.format(c1,c2)
        L=L+(z,)
    print('create table {} {})'.format(b,s),L)
    
    c.execute("create table {}{})".format(b,s),L)
    a=1
    data=[]
    while a!=0:
        for i in range(n):
            print(L[i])
            temp=input('enter integer/string')
            if temp=='integer':
                o=int(input('enter the integer'))
                data.append(o)
            elif temp=='string':
                p=input('enter string')
                data.append(p)
                
        c.execute('insert into {} values{}'.format(b,s),data)
        a=int(input('enter 0 to stop adding values'))
    x.commit()
```

can anyone say what is wrong in this code which is intended to input and create the table in MYsql??
the error is syntax error? is the problem with the version of python used??
is there anything i can do?

Comment: What do you get in your **print('create table {}{})'.format(b,s),L)**

Comment: after the recent edit the output goes like
create table student(%s,%s) ('student varchar(30)', 'rollno integer')

Comment: i just added the code for inserting as well- the edit

Comment: Does it give you any error traces? Outline What actually happens- does it insert the data?